# How can I update a group price programmatically in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to update my group prices (**I have one customer group with id =4**)
but I am stack...

First I need to **get a product by SKU**(in my example sku=1838) 
and then get the price and group price of this specific product.**This I have done it**

I have made the script below which runs in Magento 1.7.02.
It justs gets the product by SKU and gets also its price.

I have 2 questions

**a) How can i get the group price of this specific SKU?**

**b) And how can I update only the group price?**

the script that I have made so far is below.

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    require 'app/Mage.php';

    if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
        echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
        exit;
    }

    // Only for urls
    // Don't remove this
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

    Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

    umask(0);

    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));


    $SKU = "1838";

    $productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                          ->getIdBySku(trim($SKU));

    // Initiate product model
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    // Load specific product whose tier price want to update
    $product ->load($productid);

    /* print_r($product->getData()); */
    print_r($product->getName());
    print_r($product->getPrice()); 

   ?>
```

**Could you suggest anything on a) and b) questions?**